# How to update dependencies in project.json from the CLI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

Has anyone been able to update the versions in the project.json from the CLI?

The nuget docs specifically say it is not compatible with project.json (https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/nuget.exe-cli-reference#update)

My end goal is to be able to have a power shell that will update only specific packages.  I have all the parsing done, and filtering to just the packages I want (our all have a common starting ie. xxx.package) but just need to essentially do a nuget update.